# Crash at creating ListView

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-listview

I'm programming an Android application using `Fragments`.

So I created a `ListView` adapter and a new `Fragment` but my application keep crashes when I try to move between `Fragments`.

my adapter :

```
public class todoAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    Context mContext;
    int layoutResourceId;
    Item data[]=null;
    public todoAdapter (Context mContext,int layoutResourceId,Item data[]) {
        super(mContext,layoutResourceId,data);
        this.mContext=mContext;
        this.layoutResourceId=layoutResourceId;
        this.data=data;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position,View convertView,ViewGroup parent){
        if(convertView==null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater=((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId,parent,false);
        }
        Item item = data[position];
        TextView Label=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewLabel);
        ImageView img=(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewImage);
        TextView Desc=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewDesc);
        Label.setText(item.itemname);
        Label.setTag(item.Itemid);
        Desc.setText(item.Describtion);
        //img.setImageDrawable(downloadImage(item.image));
        img.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        return convertView;
    }}
```

and my `Fragment`

```
public class todoFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.todo, container, false);
        rootView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        Item[] data=new Item[2];
        //    public Item(int Itemid,String itemname,String image,String Describtion) {
        data[0]=new Item(1,"HELLO","blabla","blablabla");
        data[1]=new Item(1,"HELLO2","blabla","blablabla");
        ListView x=(ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.todolistview);
        todoAdapter adapter=new todoAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.todo_item,data);
        x.setAdapter(adapter);
        x.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
               // Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"FFF",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Done", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

logcat:

```
08-11 22:35:58.186    3752-3752/syriatel.nowwhat D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
08-11 22:35:58.186    3752-3752/syriatel.nowwhat W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x64d69b20)
08-11 22:35:58.186    3752-3752/syriatel.nowwhat I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 3752 SIG: 9
08-11 22:35:58.186    3752-3752/syriatel.nowwhat D/AndroidRuntime﹕ procName from cmdline: syriatel.nowwhat
08-11 22:35:58.186    3752-3752/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ in writeCrashedAppName, pkgName :syriatel.nowwhat
08-11 22:35:58.186    3752-3752/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ file written successfully with content: syriatel.nowwhat StringBuffer : ;syriatel.nowwhat
08-11 22:35:58.186    3752-3752/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: syriatel.nowwhat, PID: 3752
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at syriatel.nowwhat.ui.activity.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:101)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What does your logcat say?

Comment: @Tanis.7x http://pastebin.com/RjBc7KDG

Comment: Can you point out line number 101 in your MainActivity please?

Comment: @prudhvi 
http://pastebin.com/a9RJ775F

Comment: @user2973413 what line exactly?

Comment: s.setRotation(i); @prudhvi

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, looks like the problem wasn't with the Fragment itself

it was with a handler editing element which causes the problem when moving to another fragment